# Примерное значение в case

Tags: php, switch, case

Я получаю VK сообщения, в которых содержатся команды. Например, в VK пишу боту "Привет", он по Switch отвечает на это команду "Что тебе здесь нужно?".

Если я напишу "Привет!", то ответа я уже не получаю. Как правильно написать код так, чтобы он принимал за команду сообщение, которое содержит в себе определенное слово или словосочетание? ЧТобы, например, на "Привет!" был ответ как на "Привет" (потому что основная часть текста есть).

Записаны команды так:

```
switch ($bot->command) {

    case 'привет!':
    case 'здравствуйте!':
        $bot->message
            ->text('Здравствуйте! Я всего лишь Бот, но постараюсь Вас понять.')
            // ->setKeyboard($defaultKeyboard)
            ->send();
            break;

    case 'clickbutton':
        $bot->message
            ->keyboard()
            ->row()
            ->button('Главное меню', 'primary', ['command' => 'start'])
            ->one_time() //false by default
            ->text('Вызвана команда "clickbutton" с параметром "'.$bot->payload['parametr'].'"')
            ->send();
            break;
}
```

Надеюсь, понятно объяснил, что искал.

Comment: https://secure.php.net/levenshtein

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch имхо, не для тех целей используется. Тут лучше подойдёт if-else.

```
if (strpos($bot->command, 'привет') !== false
    || strpos($bot->command, 'здравствуйте') !== false
    || **другие варианты**): {
    ...
}
else if (strpos($bot->command, '**другое слово**') !== false): {
    ...
}
```